# Harmonic Numbers give Odd Constant

Tags: analysis, number-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-numbers

When I was examining the product,

(1)  $\prod _{i=1}^{\infty } H_{i} ^{(i)}$

I noticed that product converges to a single constant, 1.6798, and does so quite quickly. Is this constant something special, or is a special value of another function, or is it just a combination of other known constants? I'm using this product as part of an investigation of differential equations of form,

(2)   $y'(x)=\prod _{i=1}^n (H_i^{(i)} x^{n-i} \space y(x)^i )  =  x^{\frac{1}{2} (n-1) n} \space y(x)^{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}\prod _{i=1}^{\infty } H_{i} ^{(i)}$,

where the product (1) above is the limiting constant of the product (2).

Answer (score 1):

A few more digits  $$  1.6798002778544903357  $$ (where the last digit shown has rounded up).  The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) doesn't recognize it, so you're probably out of luck.